# How do I understand the Javascript for a website from Chrome's dev tool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm learning web development now and have been going through many websites and looking at the source code through Chrome's developer tools. This has been helpful in understanding HTML and CSS.

However, I am unable to make any sense of the Javascript. If they link an external javascript file, I open that file and try to read through. I know its minified but I don't think I'd be able to make sense of it regardless. If they have Javascript directly in their code, I'm still unable to make sense of it.

BTW - I have gone through a few Javascript tutorials so I'm at least a little familiar with JS.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: https://devhumor.com/content/uploads//images/October2014/reading-other-peoples-code.png

Comment: Sorry but this question is not a good fit for SO because it is too broad. Go write your own JavaScript program and then you can use dev tools to help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Note:** Jumping in to reading some websites code is a pretty poor way in a lot of cases, of learning javascript. Best to write your own, and read others from a repository liek github, or pastebin, or plunkr, or jsfiddle, etc.

**That said:** 
Using your browsers debugger you can see the javascript files being used in the page. I'm guessing you already know this since you've found minified javascript files. 2 issues to address:

1. How to make sense of a minified file: firefox has an unminifier feature. Very google-able.
2. Given a javascript file, how to see what it's doing. I would suggest creating a breakpoint on a line in the javascript file that you know will be hit when you do something on the web page. Find a button in the html, see what click function is attached to it, then go into the javascript file and find that click function by name using 'ctrl-f' to find it. Then create a breakpoint on a line in the function you want to debug. As soon as the breakpoint is set, once you click the button, your deubgger will stop the code right on the breakpoint, you can then step through the code to your leasure. All of these key concepts and keywords are googleable. This should give you a headstart to answering your question.

Comment: You should move your edit to the top of this post. It is the most important part for this young developer to understand.

Comment: good idea, I've done just that. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a special button which looks like this: { }. It can be found under the source code in the Sources tab. It prettifies the code for you :D

[image: Prettify Button]